# Please spot something wrong in my code (Instantiation)

Tags: unity, c#

So, when this code runs, it will just spawn like 1000 copies of pipe(two rectangles) even with the Invoke.Here is my code.

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class generator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pipe;
    GameObject piper;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Invoke("MakePipe", 1.0f);
    }

    void MakePipe()
    {
        piper = Instantiate(pipe, new Vector3(transform.position.x, Random.Range(-9f, 9f), transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
        piper.AddComponent<Pipe>();
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Why wouldn't it? What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: After 1 second it will begin to spawn pipes every frame - even the comment above Update() says that. Every frame you call a code that waits for 1 sec to do its thing.

Comment: I want to spawn pipes in 1 second intervals

Comment: @TroyD then you need to only call it once per second instead

Comment: How will I do it?

Comment: Oh nvm I have found InvokeRepeat or something... I sort of forgot, but its in the code

Comment: The simpliest solution is, you can count elapsed time in `Update` method by `Time.deltaTime`, when it reaches the desired cooldown, you call `MakePipe`, and reset timer.

Answer (score 1):

If you fire a new Invoke every frame, you'll get a new pipe every frame after the delay finishes.

It looks like you want something much simpler:

```
IEnumerator Start() { 
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        MakePipe();
    }
}
```

This starts when the script is loaded/enabled, waits one second, makes a pipe, then waits another second, in a loop forever, with no messy looking up of method name strings.